# React : How to divide my screen into 10/90 column ratio

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I simply want to divide my screen in the ratio 10/90 of the entire screen.

```
// what I have done

 return (
        <>
            <div class="row">
<div className="col-md-4" >
   <div class="leftside">
  left


   </div>
  
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="rightside">     
   <Paper elevation={3} >
right
</Paper>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

        </>
    )
}
```

This solution gives me about 60/40 ratio, how can I get 10/90 ratio

Comment: What library are u using for grid layout?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using MUI.

https://mui.com/components/grid/#main-content

You can find out by looking for "Responsive values" here.

```
<Grid container columns={{ md: 10 }}>
  <Grid item xs={1} />
  <Grid item xs={9} />
</Grid>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Using pure HTML and CSS. (Can be easily copied to react with some trivial changes)

The html goes as follows -

```
<div class="main">
  <div class = "small" >
    left
  </div>
  
  <div class = "large" >
    right
  </di>
</div>
```

and this is the css part -

```
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  
}

.small {
  width: 10%;
  background: red;
  height: fit-content;
}

.large {
  width: 90%;
  background: green;
   height: fit-content;
}
```

The height part is just for illustration purpose.